# Что такое и что означает термин Digest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Не могу понять фразу вычислить **дайджест** сообщения из данных. Какой синоним можно подобрать к данному слову?

Comment: синоним - хеш-функция

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дайджест - это вывод хеш функции. Хеш-функция - это однонаправленная функция, т.е. которую нельзя обратить. Существует много реализация хеш-функций. Суть их применения может заключаться в таких примерах:

**Пример 1:** У Вас есть, например, файл. Вы хотите убедиться что этот файл не менялся с некоторого момента. Вы вычисляете хеш функцию в "этом моменте". Через некоторое время вы снова вычисляете хеш-функцию и сравниваете значения.

**Пример 2:** Сервер должен Вас как-то аутентифицировать. Если он будет хранить Ваш пароль, то хакер, получив доступ к базе, сможет его узнать. Но сервер может хранить дайджест вашего пароля. В таком случае, при попытка аутентифицироваться. сервер вычислит дайджест и сравнит с имеющимся. Хакер не сможет расшифровать дайджест (по определнию хеш-функции).

**Пример 3:** Вы хотите подписать документ электронной подписью. Вы вычисляете дайджест документа и шифруете его закрытым ключом. Любой желающий, может посчитать дайджест документа, а также расшифровать зашифрованный дайджест Вашим открытым ключом, и сравнить их. Таким образом человек убедится, что (а) - **ВЫ** подписали это документ, (б) - Вы подписали **ЭТОТ** документ.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, но остался один вопрос: дайджест и зашифрованные данные это получается не одно и то же? Читаю статью, где рассказывается, что при получении зашифрованных данных нет гарантии, что они были изменены во время транспортировки. И поэтому отправитель должен вместе с зашифрованными данными отправить и дайджест. Далее сторона, получающая зашифрованные данные и дайджест сообщения, дешифрует сообщение и вычисляет дайджест. Потом он сравнивает дайджесты и делает соответствующие выводы. Я все верно понял?

Comment: Например есть сообщение "Hello World". Вычисляют дайджест ("[B@58c1c010"). Далее это сообщение шифруют (Например "34bmgltr"). Отправляют получателю. Он в свою очередь дешифрует сообщение(34bmgltr) и в результате получает "Hello World". После, он вычисляет дайджест расшифрованного сообщения("[B@58c1c010"). Сравнивает их и понимает что сообщение не было изменено. Все так?

Comment: Да, там где проверяется целостность переданных данных (не во всех протоколах), это так и работает.